# How can I manage multiple menus in pimcore?

Tags: php, menu, pimcore

I am not able to manage multiple pimcore menus from backend that will be used on frontend accordingly.

Is it possible to render menus on the basis of document property?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create multiple menus by using different documents as navigation roots, see:
  https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5570599

As an alternative, you could just get a document and then recurse over the childs and do the rendering yourself ():

```
function renderNav($doc) {
    // render doc here ... then:
    foreach ($doc->getChilds() as $childDoc) {
        renderNav($childDoc);
    }
}
```

Another alternative would be to build a snippet or an area block and let the user manually configure a navigation by dragging documents onto that. This is out of the scope of this answer, though.